# Hibernate objects in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a question about Hibernate objects and using its In Spring MVC Framework. I have two objects: Category and Language In ManyToOne relationship:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="language_id")
public Language getLanguage() {
return language;
}
```

I want to create action, which creates new Category with choosen Language. My form look like this:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="addCategory" name="frm" method="post">

<form:select path="language.id">
<form:options items="${languages}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>

//Other Fields like name etc.

</form:form>
```

In the controller POST method I have:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/add_category")
public String addCategory(Category category){
//code for save, redirect etc.
}
```

Suppose I choose a language with ID = 4 and name „English”, which existing in database. When I want to display language ID in metod addCategory (by **category.getLanguage().geiId()**) I have ID = 4 correctly, but when I want to display choosen language name by **category.getLanguage().getName()** I have null.

It is, perhaps, because the Spring object category doesn’t know anything about relations in Hibernate. I use Hibernate 4, Spring 3 and I am connecting to Hibernate with Spring Bean SessionFactory.

Is there any possibility to obtain full recursive object In Spring request? In other words: situation where Language in category (**category.getLanguage()**) will be full object with ID = 4 and name "English".

Thanks.

Comment: You usually hibernate in winter only

Answer (score 0):

I am having question why you need to have the name filled in your language object of the category object. Because it will be just used for the reference purpose by hibernate when you will try to store the category object in the database.

When you will fetch a category object from database using hibernate then it will return you the object containing language object with both id and value.

Still if you want ot display the name anyhow then you need to get the name by using the ID you are getting from the jsp page as selected by user.And then set that name in the object stored in your category object. Other wise you need to have another field in the jsp having `path="language.name"`.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.